# Servicio soap con hibernate devuelve colección de objetos vacía

Tags: java, webservice, hibernate, soap, maven

Estoy desarrollando un servicio soap con hibernate como ORM para gestión de clientes. Tengo un método en el servicio que me devuelve un listado de clientes. Resulta que al testear el método con soapui, no estoy recibiendo ningún dato. He depurado el código y el método si retorna una colección de clientes, por lo que supongo que no lo está enviando bien al cliente. El problema concretamente está con el campo que referencia a la tabla Estado, si quito ese campo si me devuelve bien la colección.
Esta es mi clase Cliente:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Cliente.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Cliente c")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String dni;

private int edad;

private String nombre;

private String profesion;

//uni-directional many-to-one association to Estado
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_estado")
private Estado estado;

public Cliente() {
}

public String getDni() {
    return this.dni;
}

public void setDni(String dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return this.edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getProfesion() {
    return this.profesion;
}

public void setProfesion(String profesion) {
    this.profesion = profesion;
}

public Estado getEstado() {
    return this.estado;
}

public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}
```

}

Este es mi servicio:

```
@WebService
public interface IService {
  @WebMethod
  public List<Cliente> clientes();
```

}

Y su implementación:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.udemy.service.IService")
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING) 
public class ServiceImpl implements IService{

@Override
public List<Cliente> clientes() {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("IncidenciasLink");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM cliente",Cliente.class);
    List<Cliente> personas = (List<Cliente>) q.getResultList();
    em.close();
    
    return personas;
}
```

}

Comentar que si en lugar de usar hibernate uso eclipselink, funciona correctamente. ¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Un saludo

Comment: Deberías revisar los logs del servidor, que proporcionan mucha información. No es lo mismo que la llamada te devuelva una lista vacía (el proceso ha funcionado bien pero no hay datos) que un código http 500 (ha habido un error al procesar la petición, probablemente por una excepción). Esos logs te permitirán A) aclarar si es una cuestión de JPA o de WS y B) tener más información de qué pasa. Incorpora esa información a la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. No estoy usando ningún servidor, sino que lo publico en un servidor virtual a partir de la clase Endpoint: Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:2021/incidencias", new ServiceImpl()); ¿Puedo ver de alguna forma el log? Graciass

Answer (score 0):

```
He puesto las siguientes instrucciones delante de la llamada al método publish: 

    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump","true");System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold", 
    "999999"); 

y puedo ver en la consola la siguiente información cuando invoco al método clientes(): 

    ---[HTTP request]---
    Accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Host: localhost:2021
    User-agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)
    Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
    Content-length: 206
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:ser="http://service.udemy.com/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:obtenerClientes/>
   </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>--------------------
```

Comment: Si quieres añadir información a tu pregunta, por favor edítala. En todo caso esto indica que el servidor te responde con una lista vacía de clientes; no hay ningún error. Hay algo en la configuración de JPA que hace que la consulta no te devuelva resultados.

Comment: Tiene que deberse a la configuración de hibernate. Si utilizo eclipselink como orm, funcionq bien. Pero me interesa usar hibernate. ¿Alguna idea de cual puede ser el error? Gracias